# AVAssetWriter - Max supported resolution for each device

Tags: ios, avassetwriter

the title says it, I want to know the max resolution for each device before I start encoding a video and getting an error.
I was thinking if there is something like the AVCaptureDevice supportsAVCaptureSessionPreset: .. but for regular encoding using AVAssetWriter.

Regards,
Thanks for your help.